# Pulling data from multiple input boxes in foreach loop using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, input

I am creating an order form for a project. I pulled data from the database with the Foreach loop to the table I created. But when I multiply the quantity and unit price data, the code works only for the data in the first row of the table. How can I revise this code for all incoming loop data?

Cart.php:

```
<form action="" method="POST">

<table class="table table-sm mb-3 text-center align-middle">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Product Name</th>
         <th>Quantity</th>
         <th>Unit Price</th>
         <th>Total Price</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <?php foreach($ProductTbl as $productdata){ ?>
      <tr>
         <td><?= $productdata->productname ?></td>
         <td><input class="w-25 text-center quantity" type="text" name="quantity[]" value="0"></td>
         <td><input class="w-25 text-center unitprice" type="text" name="unitprice[]" value="<?= $productdata->unitprice ?>" disabled="disabled"></td>
         <td><input class="w-25 text-center totalprice" type="text"  name="totalprice[]" value="" disabled="disabled"> €</td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.quantity').keyup(function() {
    var quantity = $('.quantity').val();
    var unitprice = $('.unitprice').val();
    var totalprice = $('.totalprice').val();
 
    var result = quantity * unitprice;
      $('.totalprice').val(result);
    });
  });
});
```

Print:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zEC9.jpg)

How do I edit the code to run on all lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've given your inputs a `class`, not an `id`. This means you cannot easily distinguish between them. However, with a bit of clever JQuery code you can identify the table row in which the quantity was changed, and then get the `quantity` and `unitprice` and set the `totalprice`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.quantity').keyup(function() {
        let tableRow = $(this).parent().parent();
        let quantity = tableRow.find('.quantity').val();
        let unitprice = tableRow.find('.unitprice').val(); 
        let totalprice = quantity * unitprice;
        tableRow.find('.totalprice').val(totalprice);
    })
});
```

So here we take the quantity input, `$(this)`, and get the parent twice: First the `<td></td>` and then the `<tr></tr>`. We store this in `tableRow`. Given that we now know the table row, we can get access to the inputs by using [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

For example code see: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/oNMjqLd

Comment: this code worked fine. thank you for your help.